# PyOpenGL GLUT error NULL display callback not permitted

Tags: python, glut, pyopengl, freeglut

I'm trying to create a window via glut in a class called Window. However when I run the function display(self), I get this error :

*freeglut (foo): Fatal error in program.  NULL display callback not permitted in GLUT 3.0+ or freeglut 2.0.1+*

When I use glut in main.py, I don't get this error and I don't understand why. Any help would be appreciated.

This is my main.py :

```
def main():
    window = Window(100, 500, 0, 0, "pipo")
    window.display()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My Window class :

```
class Window:
    def __init__(self, height, width, x, y, title):
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.title = title
        self.initWindow()

    def initWindow(self):
        glutInit()  # Initialize a glut instance which will allow us to customize our window
        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA)  # Set the display mode to be colored
        glutInitWindowSize(self.width, self.height)  # Set the width and height of your window
        glutInitWindowPosition(self.x, self.y)  # Set the position at which this windows should appear
        wind = glutCreateWindow(self.title)  # Give your window a title

    def clear(self):
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

    def display(self):
        glutDisplayFunc(self.clear())  # Tell OpenGL to call the showScreen method continuously
        glutIdleFunc(self.clear())  # Draw any graphics or shapes in the showScreen function at all times
        glutMainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

`self.clear()` is a method call. You have to pass the method object to the function instead of calling the method (`self.clear` instead of `self.clear()`):

<s>`glutDisplayFunc(self.clear())`</s>
<s>`glutIdleFunc(self.clear())`</s>

```py
glutDisplayFunc(self.clear)
glutIdleFunc(self.clear)
```

Note that when you do `glutDisplayFunc(self.clear())` the `clear` method is called and the return value of the`clear method`( `None`) is passed to the function.